# Buttons un-clickable in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 buttons in a LinearLayout, but they are un-clickable in their current layout. I have tried using breakpoints/Toasts to test and they are definitely not being pressed. I'm sure its something very simple. Here is the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Bjork">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Bjork"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="290dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#ffcc66"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <include layout="@layout/profile_header"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="@color/Bjork">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/tabLayout"
            android:background="@color/Bjork"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<View
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:alpha="0"
    >
</View>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/fab_margin">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/take_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        android:background="@color/Transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_take_photo_black"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:enabled="true"

        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/library"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Library"
        android:background="@color/Transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/library"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the Java code:

```
 takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
    takePhoto.setClickable(true);
    takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
Button library = (Button) findViewById(R.id.library);
library.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.IMAGE_PICK);
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your java code.

Comment: can you please post your java code?

Comment: `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: and post the complete layout xml please. is there a view overlapping the button?

Comment: are you using a clicklistener in java code? as I dont see the other way i.e onclick in xml.

Comment: Show your java code please

Comment: Did't find `take_photo` in your xml

Answer (score 1):

Check wether there is something in front of them, or bring them to front with: `library.bringToFront();` and `takePhoto.bringToFront();`

**Update**

```
takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
});
```

Comment: you might want to lowercase the start of the those methods, but no, they didn't work.

Comment: No worries, assumed it was :)

Comment: I have to ask thou, are they visible? Because your code looks fine, and if you say they are not getting clicked it has to be a layout thing

Comment: like for example you might want to try changing layout_height from 0 to something else

Comment: Yep, very visible. It has me baffled. I'm digging through the code (I'm new to the codebase, and android in general), but I'm at a loss. And everyones away for Xmas time so there is no one to ask!

Comment: adjusting the heights didn't fix it unfortunately

Comment: And if you try printing something just before `dispatchTakePictureIntent();` it doesn't print anything?

Comment: ok, let's see, you could check wether the id is ok and you actually see your buttons from the java class. Try making them do something before the onClickListener, like for ex. change their color: `button.setBackground(0xff99cc00);` to see if it works. This way we can at least narrow it down

Comment: Yep, that changes the button colour

Comment: ok, then it is definetly a layout thing, that is the only possibility. Then again if the button is visible and there is nothing in front of it, it should be clickable.

Comment: try:  `android:focusable = "false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode = "false"` in yout buttons' xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98702/discussion-between-irina-avram-and-spogebob92).